# print char pointer value in c

Tags: c, pointers, pointer-arithmetic

*-: was trying to learn pointers in c :-*

I couldn't print the value at the character pointer, rest of the program works fine.
It just prints a blank space, didn't get any error though.

```
#include<stdio.h>

void main() {
    int num, *num_ptr;
    char ch, *ch_ptr;

    printf("Enter a number and a single character : ");
    scanf("%d%c",&num,&ch);

    num_ptr = &num;
    ch_ptr = &ch;

    //printf("\ncontent at num_ptr = %p \n",num_ptr);
    //printf("content at ch_ptr = %p\n",ch_ptr);
    //printf("value of the content at num_ptr = %d\n",*num_ptr);

    /* error part */
        printf("value of the content at ch_ptr = %c\n",*ch_ptr);
    /* error part */

    //printf("\n");
    //printf("num_ptr + 2 = %p\n",num_ptr+2);
    //printf("ch_ptr + 2 = %p\n",ch_ptr+2);
    //printf("\n");
    //printf("num_ptr + 1 = %p\n",++num_ptr);
    //printf("num_ptr - 1 = %p\n",--num_ptr);
    //printf("ch_ptr + 1 = %p\n",++ch_ptr);
    //printf("ch_ptr - 1 = %p\n",--ch_ptr);
    //printf("\n");
    //printf("num_ptr + 5 = %p\n",num_ptr+5);
    //printf("ch_ptr - 5 = %p\n\n",--ch_ptr-5);
}
```

[image: program output]

Comment: What did you type?  What did you see?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I've update my code with the output

Comment: It’s because the first char which `scanf` encounters the a blank space (between 21 and t). Use `%d %c` if you want to use the space and have it correctly parsed.

Comment: Your code printed the space that it read.  The `%c` does not skip blanks, unlike most other conversions (`%n` and `%[…]` scan sets are the other non-skipping conversions).  Add a space between the conversion specifications in your `scanf()` format string.

Comment: You entered a blank space between `21` and `t`

Comment: To fix it you have to put a space between %d%c.

Comment: Posting text as text is preferred and more useful than posting text as a picture.

Comment: It's often useful to enclose a character between markers when printing: `”… ‘%c’\n”` so you can see spaces and newlines, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your input is `21 t`, which means that `scanf` will read 21 into `num`, and the in-between whitespace into `ch`, which is what you specify in the first argument to `scanf`. You either separate the format specifiers by a blank space, i.e. `%d %c`, or enter the input without the whitespace, hence `21t`.